# How to deserialize custom payload response in Dialogflow v2?

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I'm developing my own chatbot for messenger with Dialogflow v2 and the Node.js client SDK. But I've a problem with custom payloads. When I use the console provided by Dialogflow, I have a response which looks like this :

```
{ "payload": { "facebook": { "attachment": { "payload": { ...
```

But, when I get the response from my JS server, the custom payload has been serialized. Here is the object I receive :

```
{ facebook: { structValue: { fields: [Object] }, kind: 'structValue' } }
```

Is it possible to deserialize this object in order to get the same custom payload structure that I've provided in Dialogflow ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is built using [Struct protocols](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message)

In order to convert that you would need to use google proto buffer i.e [google.protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/)
I used the below code to do this.

```
import google.protobuf  as pf
pf.json_format.MessageToJson(response.query_result.fulfillment_messages[1].payload, including_default_value_fields=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Apparently Dialogflow released their own solution with the samples for the Node.js SDK: [dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/samples/structjson.js](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/f4017c534bae7f2b088e5e7d2da3a60cbf80642f/samples/structjson.js)

Alternatively to the solution of Vikas Jain you could write your own (recursive) conversion function.

Something like:

```
processCustomPayloadMessage(object) {
  let outputMessage = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {};
  Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value.kind == 'structValue') {
      outputMessage[key] = this.processCustomPayloadMessage(value.structValue.fields);
    } else if (value.kind == 'listValue') {
      outputMessage[key] = this.processCustomPayloadMessage(value.listValue.values);
    } else if (value.kind == 'stringValue') {
      outputMessage[key] = value.stringValue;
    } else if (value.kind == 'boolValue') {
      outputMessage[key] = value.boolValue;
    } else {
      outputMessage[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return outputMessage;
}

// call this method with your response message
this.processCustomPayloadMessage(message.payload.fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, and it's very awful & painful this boring these added k,v that we receive as webhooks in our server, it's because of the **[structJson](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/structjson.js)** I use NodeJS and here is a solution I came to:

```js
const JSON_SIMPLE_VALUE_KINDS = new Set([
  'numberValue',
  'stringValue',
  'boolValue',
]);


function valueProtoToJson(proto) {
  if (!proto || !proto.kind) {
    return null;
  }

  if (JSON_SIMPLE_VALUE_KINDS.has(proto.kind)) {
    return proto[proto.kind];
  } else if (proto.kind === 'nullValue') {
    return null;
  } else if (proto.kind === 'listValue') {
    if (!proto.listValue || !proto.listValue.values) {
      console.warn('Invalid JSON list value proto: ', JSON.stringify(proto));
    }
    return proto.listValue.values.map(valueProtoToJson);
  } else if (proto.kind === 'structValue') {
    return structProtoToJson(proto.structValue);
  } else {
    console.warn('Unsupported JSON value proto kind: ', proto.kind);
    return null;
  }
}


function structProtoToJson(proto) {
  if (!proto || !proto.fields) {
    return {};
  }
  const json = {};
  for (const k in proto.fields) {
    json[k] = valueProtoToJson(proto.fields[k]);
  }
  return json;
}

Once added, you apply this function to your result : 

var correctJSON = valueProtoToJson(Response_dialogflow.fulfillmentMessages[0].payload.fields.facebook)
```

You simply apply the  ***valueProtoToJson*** function to the dsired element from Dialogflow response where the payload is : Response_dialogflow.fulfillmentMessages[0]... or [1](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/structjson.js)...

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [`pb-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pb-util) for converting from protobuf to JavaScript objects in node. According to [this comment on `nodejs-dialogflow`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/97#issuecomment-477793587), this is a temporary solution until this is included in the client library.

Answer (score 0):

How i decode dialogflow

Format of the response from my API to the (dialogflow webhook fulfillment request)

```
const response = {
"status":200,
"messages":[{},{} ...]
}
```

How i read the response from My API to send chat bot or to do something..

```
var express = require('express');
var {value} = require('pb-util');
var router = express.Router();

...

const status = value.decode(data[0].queryResult.webhookPayload.fields.status);
const messages = value.decode(data[0].queryResult.webhookPayload.fields.messages);
```

[pb-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pb-util) convert my status and messages into normal JSON object